# unzip is not unzipping contents of directory

Tags: zip

I am unzipping a zip archive (created in Windows I think) in Redhat Linux and it is unzipping and creating directories, but it is not unzipping the contents of the directories.

In other words, if I do this command:

```
unzip -l -P mypw myarchive.zip | more
```

Then it lists all the files in the archive correctly. But if I then try to unzip it:

```
unzip -P mypw myarchive.zip archive_content
```

Then when I look in archive_content it has the complete directory structure from the archive, but all the files are missing.

Comment: enough free disk space?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes.

Comment: Did you try `unzip -P mypw myarchive.zip` or `unzip -P mypw myarchive.zip archive_content\*` ?

Comment: And there are no error messages, such as `unzip` saying it doesn’t know how to extract the files?

Comment: @StephenKitt There are no error messages. It just silently finishes after writing the directories.

Comment: What’s `unzip`’s exit status?

Comment: @StephenKitt How do I determine that? The command just completes like any other command does.

Comment: `echo $?` as the first command after `unzip` (so `unzip ...`, wait for it to complete, `echo $?`).